# I want the Google Cloud Storage bucket to be accessible only from my app (mobile/web)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, identity-management

This is driving me crazy…

I want to store images into Google Cloud Storage and the images to be only accessible from our app, because the uploaded image may contain privacy sensitive content.

I kept googling last couple of hours and haven’t got a clue, and feeling dumb of myself…

ChatGPT suggested to create a signed URL, which makes sense, but do we need to go that far, to satisfy this seemingly common requirement?

My first intuition was that I could use IAM and Service Account, but… it didn’t lead anywhere for me.

If Google doesn’t offer this capability but AWS does, I want to hear that too.

Comment: What's the size of the biggest image? In addition, is the content shareable among all the users, or each user must access to only a subset of images?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Probably no more than couple of hundred kb (does it matter? ). It is okay that other users can see the images as long as from within the app.

Comment: It's recommended to have a direct access to the image (with signed URL) instead of streaming the content through a service. With your current condition, the Chris solution is good: create a backend that serve your images. This backend also check the user origin/authentication and use its own service account to access the bucket.

Comment: I see. That’s a whole lot than I thought… But at least I can see the path to work. 
But if I have to create an endpoint to stream image content, i am also one step away from creating a signed URL as well, which would benefit from caching at least for couple of hours? Hmm… Anyway thanks for detailed explanations, really appreciate it!!

Answer (score 1):

You are right, there is not out of the box solution for this. Google Cloud's storage security is mainly based in IAM roles and permissions. Using signed URL's could be a feasible solution to provide temporary access to the final user to a single object, but in your case as you want to use the bucket to store and access objects from your app you should just set a service account for your app and set the right permissions according to your business needs.